# How to get data for a particular log4j2 property from an alternative source (application.properties)

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, log4j2

Having a standard configuration for log4j2 and spring property-file on classpath application.property.

**log4j2.xml**

```
<Properties>
        ...
        <Property name="APP_LOG_ROOT">${bundle:application:log.root.dir}</Property>
        ...
</Properties>
```

**application.properties**

```
...
log.root.dir=/opt/tomcat/logs
...
```

The data is read into the log4j2.xml correctly, but what if I want to get an alternative property when creating an artifact with maven and put diferent application.property:

```
mvn clean install -Dapplication.properties.path=file:/some_path/application.properties
```

?
After that, I can correctly read the new properties.

```
@Value("${log.root.dir}")
    private String ololo;
```

but the log4j2 cannot do this on its own.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use *any* value from Spring's [`Environment`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/env/Environment.html) in a Log4j2 configuration file, you need to use the [Spring Boot Lookup](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/lookups.html#SpringLookup):

- for Spring Boot 2.x this requires an additional dependency:

  ```xml
  <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>log4j-spring-boot</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
  </dependency>
  ```
- since Spring Boot 3.x the lookup is included in `spring-boot`.

After adding the Spring Boot lookup, you just need to replace

```
${bundle:application:log.root.dir}
```

with

```
${spring:log.root.dir}
```

**Edit**: Unlike Log4j, which starts as one of the first systems of an application, Spring's `Environment` is available only some time later.

In order for the lookup to work:

- you can either call your file `log4j2-spring.xml` as [Bojan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72685472/how-to-get-data-for-a-particular-log4j2-property-from-an-alternative-source-app/72688941#comment132038715_72688941) suggests,
- or you can use a Spring arbiter to protect the parts that use the Spring lookup (cf. [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77071522/11748454)):

  ```xml
  <Select>
      <SpringProfile name="default">
          <Property name="APP_LOG_ROOT" value="${spring:log.root.dir}"/>
      </SpringProfile>
      <DefaultArbiter>
          <Property name="APP_LOG_ROOT" value="...folder for initial logs..."/>
      </DefaultArbiter>
  </Select>
  ```

Comment: and `log4j2.xml` should be `log4j2-spring.xml`.

Comment: Without renaming file as said by @BojanVukasovic, Spring property weren't resolved. Renaming `log4j2.yaml` to`log4j2-spring.yaml` (so, also validated for `yaml` ones) do the job. Thanks !