# How to use the Log4j2 SpringProfile arbiter to alter a property value

Tags: log4j2

According to the [docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/configuration.html#arbiters) it should be possible to use the `SpringProfile` arbiter to choose whether a given "node" is included, based on the active Spring Boot profile; so I assumed this should work:

```
    <Properties>
        <SpringProfile name="dev">
            <Property name="logdir" value="/tmp/log"/>
        </SpringProfile>
        <SpringProfile name="docker">
            <Property name="logdir" value="/var/log"/>
        </SpringProfile>
        <Property name="logfile" value="users.log"/>
    </Properties>
```

However, this does not appear to configure the property (at all) as expected (although, in a different part of my configuration, this works):

```
    <Loggers>
        <!-- LOG everything at INFO level, unless the `debug` Spring Profile is used -->
        <SpringProfile name="debug">
            <Root level="debug">
                <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
            </Root>
        </SpringProfile>
        <SpringProfile name="!debug">
            <Root level="info">
                <AppenderRef ref="Console"/>
                <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
            </Root>
        </SpringProfile>
    </Loggers>
```

My guess is that either (a) I'm doing it wrong in the `Properties` or (b) somehow the `Properties` nodes are not affected by the SpringProfile arbiter.

I am aware that I could just duplicate all the `Appender` configuration to make it do what I want (or use different files, for that matter); but it seems... well, wasteful - all I want is a different directory for my logs, based on the Spring Profile.

Please note that I am aware of all the possible weird and wonderful ways in which this can be otherwise accomplished; here, I'm only interested in whether I can influence the value of Log4j `Property` via a `SpringProfile` arbiter - many thanks for any advice you may have!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can freely use `SpringProfile` inside a `<Properties>` node, but you need to remember that a `log4j2.xml` configuration file is used twice during the lifecycle of a Spring Boot application:

- Log4j Core is initialized almost as soon as your application starts. At this time no Spring `Environment` is available and `${logdir}` expands to `${logdir}`,
- as soon as the [`ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/event/ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent.html) event is triggered, Spring Boot reconfigures Log4j Core again. From this moment `${logdir}` will expand properly.

Therefore you also need to set a value for `logdir` that will be used in the initial phase:

```xml
<Select>
    <SpringProfile name="dev">
        <Property name="logdir" value="/tmp/log"/>
    </SpringProfile>
    <SpringProfile name="docker">
        <Property name="logdir" value="/var/log"/>
    </SpringProfile>
    <DefaultArbiter>
        <Property name="logdir" value="..."/>
    </DefaultArbiter>
</Select>
```

**Remark**: you can also switch to two configuration files:

- a `log4j2.xml` for the startup phase of your application (no `SpringProfile`s allowed),
- a `log4j2-spring.xml` for the runtime phase of your application.

**Edit:** Since [issue #1783](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/issues/1783) was solved in version 2.21.0 I simplified the configuration.

For older versions you need to use the workaround:

```xml
<Property name="logdir" value="..."/>
<SpringProfile name="dev">
    <Property name="logdir" value="/tmp/log"/>
</SpringProfile>
<SpringProfile name="docker">
    <Property name="logdir" value="/var/log"/>
</SpringProfile>
```

and ignore the error messages.

Comment: Thanks, @piotr - appreciated. In the end, I switched back to logback: the effort of using log4j2 didn't really justified. One thing that is (somewhat) annoying is that the documentation, while explictly describing the use of `SpringProfile` entirely ignores this issue, which then leads to a lot of wasted time.

Comment: @MarcoMassenzio: thanks for confirming that documentation is our Achilles' heel. In the near future we'll spend a lot of time improving it.

Comment: also, for the record, you guys are awesome :) I love OSS (and when time allows, I try to either contribute or publish my own code as Apache 2 licensed).  Documentation is hard! I don't really think that we (as an industry) have really cracked the problem, although now LLMs may pave the way to have the machine do the tedious work! Thanks again, this is really appreciated <3