# Dynamic Log path value in the Log4j2.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, logging, log4j2

Facing issue while substituting the dynamic log path value in the external log4j2.properties in the Spring boot application during startup

here the log4j2.properties whhich is kept outside of the classpath ( in directory) .kindly help

Your response will help in resolving this issue.

```
status=warn
name=RollingFileLogConfig
property.basePath= ${sys:log.path}
appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = applicationStart
appender.rolling.fileName= ${basePath}/Application.log
```

i am getting exception while i pass  the value in the runtime of the application from the CMD

ERROR StatusConsoleListener Unable to create file ${sys:log.path}/Application.log
java.io.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

But if i try to set the value like this:

```
System.setProperty("logPath", "/test/path");
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
```

It is working
but i try to get the value from the application.yml file log path is not creating ? help me on this

Comment: Why don't you share that command line and the error that you are getting as part of the question? Use edit. And what 'dynamic' value are you talking about? Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Can you review the details of your question? The mismatch between the file name in your error message `appln.log` and config file `Application.log` suggests that Log4j Core is using a different configuration file (e.g. `log4j2.xml` or `log4j2-test.properties`).

Comment: How do you provide the value of the Java system property `log.path`? Did you try providing it as JVM argument `-Dlog.path=...`?

Comment: java -Dlog.path=/path/to/logs -jar xxxx.jar

Comment: Does [How to get data for a particular log4j2 property from an alternative source (application.properties)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72685472/11748454) answer you question?